# I would like to customize tumblr s lightbox

Tags: tumblr

I hope someone can help me with my problem with tumblrs lightbox.
I only have very basic html knowledge and because of that, I thought, it might be a good idea to work with tumblr themes. Everything works fine, but if you click on a picture on my site, tumblrs lightbox shows up and its back button does not bring you back to my main site, instead it shows the picture on another site.
Thats annoying, but I do not know how to change the options of the tumblr lightbox back button?

http://andreasschmitten20062010.tumblr.com/

Is there anyone here, who knows something about tumblr and how to change this?

Also it would be great if you could move through the other pictures from the lightbox.

Thank you very much
Andre

Comment: I think its the default behavior of Tumblr's lightbox, click the back button and it will bring you to the permalink page of the image, you can't change it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly you can't customise the default Tumblr image viewer or its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `{LinkOpenTag}` and `{LinkCloseTag}` surrounding the image tag.

Eg.

```
{LinkOpenTag}
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
{LinkCloseTag}
```

becomes

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
```